# timedatectl not returning the right info

Tags: 18.04, timezone

I have 2 servers running the exact same Ubuntu and kernel versions. Both have identical HW and have been booted with the same USB drive.

```
user@server1:~$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.6 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
user@server1:~$
user@server1:~$ uname -a
Linux satlab-rs1 4.15.0-156-generic #163-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 19 23:31:58 UTC 2021 
x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
user@server1:~$
```

However, on server1, timedatectl returned the right TZ but the wrong date and time

```
user@server1:~$ timedatectl
                  Local time: Fri 2021-08-27 02:24:42 +08
              Universal time: Thu 2021-08-26 18:24:42 UTC
                    RTC time: Sun 2006-01-01 05:46:28
                   Time zone: Etc/GMT-8 (+08, +0800)
   System clock synchronized: no
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
             RTC in local TZ: no
user@server1:~$
```

On server2, the returned info is correct

```
user@server2:~$ timedatectl
                  Local time: Fri 2022-04-15 21:49:00 PDT
              Universal time: Sat 2022-04-16 04:49:00 UTC
                    RTC time: Sat 2022-04-16 04:48:59
                   Time zone: America/Los_Angeles (PDT, -0700)
   System clock synchronized: no
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
             RTC in local TZ: no
user@server2:~$
```

I tried dpkg-reconfigure tzdata but that did not fix the issue, even though /etc/timezone is correct

```
user@server1:~$ cat /etc/timezone
America/Los_Angeles
user@server1:~$
```

I also used “sudo timedatectl set-timezone” but still that did not fix the issue.

Any idea what’s going on here?

Comment: Is it syncing to a time server? Can it reach it?

Comment: How do I check that? I see this "System clock synchronized: no"

Comment: Have you configured a machine as a time server somewhere on your network? Have you configured your clients to update time via a time server on your network or on the internet? Ubuntu has internet time servers configured by default, as far as I know... Those are usually identified in /etc/ntp.conf... Or /etc/chrony.conf, depending on what you are running. Some prefer not to use an internet time source and use their own time server (like me). Some people don't even run a configuration, some just use something like ntpdate to poll a time server every so often. What are you doing to get the time?